# Changing Firebase configuration at runtime on iOS

Tags: ios, firebase

For my project, I have 2 environments:

- test
- prod

and 2 localizations:

- en
- tr

and an app for each combination: (these names do not mirror Firebase project ids)

- test_en
- test_tr
- prod_en
- prod_tr

And I have a separate plist file for each of these apps in the project, with the names `Firebase-(app_type).plist` ie `Firebase-test_en.plist` or `Firebase-prod_en.plist`

I am initializing `FIRApp` using this way:

```
private func ensureLoaded() {
    let options = FIROptions(contentsOfFile: Bundle.main
        .path(forResource: "Firebase-\(firebaseApplicationName)", ofType: "plist"))!

    if nil == FIRApp(named: firebaseApplicationName) {
        FIRApp.configure(withName: firebaseApplicationName, options: options)
    }
}
```

And it seems to work ok, until I try to actually connect to firebase database, where it says:

> Firebase is not configured correctly, please call [FIRApp configure]

So my question is, how do I make firebase work where I want to dynamically change configurations? There are some other questions that describe how to change configuration based on some environment variables / compiler flags but they are all referring to changing the `plist` file, which changes the configuration during build time, but I want to change it dynamically during runtime. Is it supported at all, is there a way to make it work?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Beyond me why you were downvoted bro :-( This is a super valid Firebase question — upvoted!

Comment: Does it work the first time (i.e. before switching apps)?

Comment: No it wasn't working the first time either, but I found the bug, see the answer below. Thanks for trying to help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found what the problem was, we were using `FIRApp.auth().currentUser` somewhere in the app, which returns the auth for "default" app and since we had multiple configs, we had no notion of a "default" app, so the configuration was incomplete. I changed that to `FIRAuth(app: myApp)?.currentUser` and it works as expected now.

Comment: Good catch! Keep in mind that the same aplies to `FIRDatabase`. You need to use the `FIRDatabase.database(app:)` class method to get a valid instance. Happy hacking!

Comment: BTW, don't forget to accept your own answer... but you must wait 48 hours to do so :)